# Linear layout disable click on navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

Menu items in navigation drawer do not respond because of the linear layout.I have tried constrained layout instead of linear layout.But it gives the same results.Without that linear layout or the constrained layout the menu items are clickable and responding.
How can I fix this error and make menu items clickable with linear layout?

`<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_items">

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".homePageDuplicate">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="139dp"
            android:layout_height="166dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#FF9800/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

        <Button

            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#29A536"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_local_taxi_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="btn1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onclick" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:backgroundTint="#F1110C"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_account_balance_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:text="btn"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:onClick="onclick2" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#D1522A"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_phone_in_talk_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="9.5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:text="btn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:onClick="onclick3" />

        <Button

            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#8F7608"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_local_hospital_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:text="btn"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:onClick="onclick"/>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the order of your `NavigationView` and your `LinearLayout` so that the `NavigationView` is below your `LinearLayout` in your XML file. This ensures that the `NavigationView` is 'on top' of the `LinearLayout` when it comes to receiving click events.